# How to get VS Code to run assembly?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to code in assembly (.asm) in VS Code. I found a nice plugin for text highlighting , but couldn't find a way to actually run the code with VS Code.
the platform is ubuntu, using vmware.

Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: im trying to run it on vmware running ubuntu